# PHP video "in the database"

Tags: php, video

I'm trying to display a video using wamp and php. I'm storing the name of the video "trailer.MP4" in the database, the attribute that stores it is called VIDEO.

```
<body>
<?php 
$tituloPagina= 'PELICULAS';
include ('encabezado.php');
include("conexion.php");
$link =Conectarse();
$s = oci_parse($link, "select * from pelicula");
oci_execute($s);

echo "<table border=1 align='center'> ";
echo "<th> NUM </th> <th> NOMBRE </th> <th> DESCRIPCION </th> <th> EST</th> <th> CLAS</th><th> TRAILER </th> <th> EDIT </th> <th> DEL</th> <TR>";
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($s)) {    
        $id =$row['ID_PELICULA'];
      echo "<td>".$id."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row['NOMBRE']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row['SINOPSIS']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row['PROMOCION']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row['CLASIFICACION']."</td>";

 echo "<td><video width="320" height="240" controls><source src=".$row['VIDEO']." type="video/mp4"></video></td>";
```

When reloading the site it shows: 
[Parse Error on video tag line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMv2a.png)

The video trailer.mp4 is on the root folder for the php and website files.

I'm new to this so I feel like I'm in the dark while trying this... Got it as an assignment without any prior knowledge about the subject.

Comment: Syntax error. Missing a . after `src=".$row['VIDEO']`

Comment: @DaveJarvis the link "Parse error" is an image with the error. @Tristan,  actually that's a modified version of it, already tried it with `src=".$row['VIDEO']." type[...]` and had the same error.

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy to track this error because it's error in the syntax

change

```
echo "<td><video width="320" height="240" controls><source src=".$row['VIDEO']" type="video/mp4"></video></td>";
```

to

```
echo "<td><video width="320" height="240" controls><source src=" . $row['VIDEO'] . " type="video/mp4"></video></td>";
```

You've missed a dot.

Moreover you have literal mistake in table attribute it should be called `align` you have `aling` even better if you used css "text-align: center", you should format your code better check [PSR rules](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/)

Comment: He's also mixing & matching double quotes as quoted string and as PHP delimitters.  He should probably just use singles as outer quotes.

Comment: I missed the dot in the post but in the file (made a mistake while trying another thing). Tried it like this before: `src=".$row['VIDEO']."`.

Comment: My professor gave me the file I had this line before(displays an image): `echo "<td><img src='imagenes/Posters/".$row['VIDEO']."' width='200px' /></td>";` have to make it display the video and other stuff to the main site.

Comment: so either put relative/absolute HTTP path to file in DB and use it or in worse case put it on HTML.